# How to ascertain excesive use of my S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a S3 bucket that I use to store images for a website I manage. The bill is usually about $1/month and I store about 12.5 GB on the service. It's never really been an issue before, but recently noticed the bill has shot up to ~$10-12/month. After some investigating, data transfer from US East (Northern Virginia) data transfer to Asia Pacific (Singapore) has dramatically shot up, to almost 500GB/month.

I've looked through the bucket and don't see anything unusual. It's largely just user avatars and photos. Is there anyway I can figure out what's been transferred at such a high rate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your best course of actions is enabling access log on your S3 bucket to see what files are accessed at this rate

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/enable-server-access-logging.html

Also I had a similar issue some time ago where a S3 bucket that was only storing profil pictures started to cost a lot more that I should in data transfer.
Turn's out the issue was with the ORM packages used to interact with the database, a simple login-in of an user would create an update event (to store the new access token), but this would also load in memory the user data and for some reason the url of the profil picture was loaded too (and downloaded from the S3)

Hope it helps !

Comment: I enabled this and was able to figure out that ByteSpider is crawling my site thousands of times a day and eating up bandwidth. Thanks for the help.